# When is CGLIB proxy used by Spring AOP?

Tags: java, spring, proxy, spring-aop, cglib

I was reading some articles about Spring AOP and encountered this:

> AOP proxy: the object created by AOP to implement the aspect
>   contracts. In Spring, proxy objects can be JDK dynamic proxies or
>   CGLIB proxies. By default, the proxy objects will be JDK dynamic
>   proxies, and the object being proxied must implement an interface,
>   that will also be implemented by the proxy object. But a library like
>   CGLIB can be used to create proxies by subclassing too, so an
>   interface is not needed.

Could you look at the following structure and imagine that we want to advise `bar()` method.

```
public interface Foo {
    void foo();
}

public class FooImpl implements Foo {

    @Override
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("");
    }

    public void bar() {
        System.out.println("");
    }

}
```

Does it mean that in this case CGLIB proxy will be used?
Since JDK dynamic proxy isn't able to implement any interface in order to override `bar()` method.

Comment: It depends--how are you injecting the bean?

Answer (score 8):

Spring will only use CGLIB if you tell it to. This is enabled (for annotation based  configurations) by setting the `proxyTargetClass` element of `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` to `true`.

```
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
```

Consider this minimal example (assuming your `FooImpl` is annotated with `@Component`)

```
@Aspect
@Component
class FooAspect {
    @Before("execution(public void bar())")
    public void method() {
        System.out.println("before");
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Example.class);
        FooImpl f = ctx.getBean(FooImpl.class); // throw exception here
        f.bar();
    }
}
```

By default, `proxyTargetClass` is `false`. In this case, Spring will not use CGLIB. Because of the `@Before` advice in the `@Aspect` class, Spring will decide that it needs to proxy the `FooImpl` with a JDK proxy. Unfortunately, because of this proxying behavior, the bean actually stored in the context will be of a dynamic JDK `Proxy` type (also a subtype of the `Foo` interface) and therefore trying to get the bean with `FooImpl.class` will fail.

Even if you tried to retrieve it as a `Foo`, you wouldn't be able to invoke a `bar()` method since the proxy object isn't a `FooImpl`.

If you enable the `proxyTargetClass`, the code above works as intended, a CGLIB proxy is created, and the `@Before` advice is invoked.

Comment: Thank you, but could you explain me why an exception will be thrown in your snippet? What is the purpose of advising the method with JDK dynamic proxy if we can’t retrieve/invoke it?

Comment: @Pavel Although `FooImpl` is annotated by `@Compoent`, it's also a target for proxying because of the advice. As such, Spring will create a bean definition for it that is of the proxy type and therefore not `FooImpl`.

Answer (score 3):

See [AOP Proxies](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-introduction-proxies) in the Spring documentation:

> Spring AOP defaults to using standard JDK dynamic proxies for AOP proxies. This enables any interface (or set of interfaces) to be proxied.
>
> Spring AOP can also use CGLIB proxies. This is necessary to proxy classes rather than interfaces. By default, CGLIB is used if a business object does not implement an interface.

Answer (score -2):

Spring AOP defaults to using standard JDK dynamic proxies for AOP proxies. This enables any interface (or set of interfaces) to be proxied.

Spring AOP can also use CGLIB proxies. This is necessary to proxy classes rather than interfaces. CGLIB is used by default if a business object does not implement an interface. As it is good practice to program to interfaces rather than classes; business classes normally will implement one or more business interfaces. It is possible to force the use of CGLIB, in those (hopefully rare) cases where you need to advise a method that is not declared on an interface, or where you need to pass a proxied object to a method as a concrete type.

It is important to grasp the fact that Spring AOP is proxy-based. See Understanding AOP proxies for a thorough examination of exactly what this implementation detail actually means.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-introduction